# Is it possible to link a windows form in C#(preferable) or vc++ in an MFC Application in MSVC2010?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I am working on a text re-positioning(in Urdu) application and want to enter text in Urdu in my MFC application. Now, I cannot Localize my MFC dialog but a windows Form has that option to localize the language from the keyboard(so I can enter text in Urdu with a different font). I did this on a windows form in c#(text to image conversion).. and it worked just fine. Now I need to integrate it with my older application(Which was made using MFC library) on a click of a button. 
In short, all I want is to be able to get Urdu text from textbox in my MFC app. 
Thanks guys, A quick reply is highly appreciated.

Comment: *"I cannot Localize my MFC dialog"* This is wrong/why not?

Answer (score 0):

If you know an ID of your textbox (CEdit?) control, and you know the title of your MFC dialog, the possible solution could be:

Use FindWindow to get the window handle of your MFC dialog:

```
HWND hMFCDialog = FindWindow(0, <your dialog title>);
```

Using this handle enumerate all its child windows by calling:

```
EnumChildWindows(hMFCDialog, EnumChildProc, 0);
```

Inside enumerating function use GetDlgCtrlID to get control ID for each control and compare it with your textbox's ID. When the correct ID is found, use the window handle to get the text:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) 
{
   int ID = GetDlgCtrlId(hwnd);
   if (ID == myTextBoxID)
   {
       GetWindowText(hwnd, textbuffer, textbufferlength);
   }
}
```